# before_filter checking multiple roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, authorization, roles, before-filter

In application_controller I have the following method:

```
  def authorized_for_roles(*roles)
    roles.each{|role_name| return true if current_user.has_role?(role_name)}
    false
  end
```

In one of my controllers, I have

```
private

  def authorize_administration
    authorized_for_roles :administrator
  end
```

I am calling authorize_administration in my before_filter.  Currently getting 'undefined method roles" error.  Can someone tell me where I've gone wrong?  the current_user is valid/defined, and the role can be checked.

Thanks

Comment: Can you include the 'has_role?' method from the User model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the error really in the authorized_for_roles def, or perhaps in the User model?  Did you define has_many :roles for User?

Comment: the user has_one :role, but what I'm after is checking for multiple roles -- for example I might call authorized_for_roles :administrator, :moderator, so I can authorize users with either of those roles for the controller actions.

Comment: OK I just went back & it seems that my user belongs_to :role